# Trouble With Scrollbar For Text Widget

Tags: python, text, tkinter, widget

I am simply trying to make a scrollbar for the list of checkbuttons that appear on my text widget. So far the scrollbar appears in the correction location and the correct size but it is greyed out and will not allow me to scroll. Does anyone known what the problem might be?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("750x500")

checkbox_frame = Frame(master, borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=1,
                                 highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
checkbox_frame.pack(expand=False,ipadx=100,ipady=100)

text = Text(checkbox_frame, cursor="arrow")

vsb = Scrollbar(text, orient = tkinter.VERTICAL)
vsb.config(command=text.yview)

text.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

text.configure(state="disabled")

vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.place(x=3,y=0)
enable = []
for x_number_of_items in range(15):
    enable.append("Robot Test File "+ str(x_number_of_items))
list_for_listbox = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

for item in list_for_listbox:
    listbox.insert(END, item)
    for y in enable:
        globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)] = BooleanVar()
        globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(item, y)] = Checkbutton(text, text=y, variable=globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)])

def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
    w = evt.widget
    x=0
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print ('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))

    for y in enable:
        for item in list_for_listbox:
            globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(item, y)].place_forget()
        globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(value, y)].place(x=0,y=0+x)
        x+=50

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

def printcommand():
    for item in list_for_listbox:
        for y in enable:
            print(item + " [" + y + "] " + str(globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)].get()))

print(enable)

printbutton = Button(master,text="Print",command= printcommand)
printbutton.place(x=100, y=250)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your scrollbar is for the disabled `Text` widget which has no text in it, of course it won't scroll.  Even if you were to enable the `Text` and put in multiple lines, as you scroll you will notice the checkboxes won't scroll with the scrollbar either way.  You will need to bind the scrollbar with the checkboxes instead.  I would highly suggest you consider approaching this problem from an OOP approach, i.e. using `class`es instead of manipulating `globals()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong with your code.

The first thing I would change is to stop trying to dynamically generate variable names. That is virtually never a good idea, and only serves to make your code extremely hard to understand and debug.

Instead, store the checkbuttons and variables in a list or dictionary. There's no requirement that each checkbutton or variable have a distinct variable associated with it.

For example, the following code illustrates how to create a bunch of checkbuttons and variables in a loop:

```
for i in range(15):
    label = "Robot Test File {}".format(i)
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=label, variable=var)
    cb_vars.append(var)
    checkbuttons.append(checkbutton)
```

With that, you can now reference the checkbuttons and their variables as you would with any list: `cb_vars[0].get()`, etc. If you prefer to be able to refer to them by name then you can use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
cb_vars = {}
checkbuttons = []
for i in range(15):
    label = "Robot Test File {}".format(i)
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=label, variable=var)
    cb_vars[label] = var
    checkbuttons.append(checkbutton)

    text.window_create("insert", window=checkbutton)
    text.insert("end", "\n")
```

With the above, you can do `cb_vars['Robot Test File 1'].get()` to get the value of checkbutton number 1. You can of course use anything you want as the index.

Second, the text widget can't scroll things added to the widget with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. The widget can only scroll things added as content to the widget. To add a checkbutton you can use the `window_create` method. Assuming you want each checkbutton on a separate line, you'll need to add a newline after each checkbutton.

For example, here's how you could create 15 checkboxes in a scrollable text widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, height=5)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

cb_vars = []
checkbuttons = []
for i in range(15):
    label = "Robot Test File {}".format(i)
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=label, variable=var)
    var.set(False)

    text.window_create("insert", window=checkbutton)
    text.insert("end", "\n")
    cb_vars.append(var)
    checkbuttons.append(checkbutton)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but how would you implement the "<<ListboxSelect>>"? I would greatly appreciate if you included that as well.

Comment: It looks even better if you add `cursor="arrow"` to the checkbutton arguments.