# Scrollable Checkbuttons From Selected Listbox Items

Tags: python, tkinter

How do you add a scroll bar to a list of atleast 20 checkboxes per listbox item? I want the checkboxes to be within some sort of text widget that can be scrolled. This is a continued question from [PREVIOUS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727332/python-tkinter-create-checkbox-list-from-listbox/52728207?noredirect=1#comment92443964_52728207).

Comment: For each item in the listbox, does it have the exact same number of checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** because of reasoning in the comments see: Thanks to [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52745199/8980073)  🙂 :

**[VERSION WITH DICTIONARY]**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def myfunction(event):
    canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))


def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
    w = evt.widget
    x = 0
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))

    for y in enable:
        for item in list_for_listbox:
            checkbuttons[item][y][1].grid_forget()
        checkbuttons[value][y][1].grid(row=x, column=0)
        # Label(frame2, text="some text").grid(row=x, column=1)
        x += 1


def printcommand():
    for item in list_for_listbox:
        for y in enable:
            print(item + " [" + y + "] " + str(checkbuttons[item][y][0].get()))


master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Checkboxes test")
master.geometry("750x500")

# enable = ['button 1', 'button 2', 'button 3', 'button 4', 'button 5', 'button 6', 'button 7']
enable = []
for x_number_of_items in range(1, 15):
    enable.append("button " + str(x_number_of_items))

list_for_listbox = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.place(x=5, y=5, width=100, height=10 + 16*len(list_for_listbox))
listbox.update()

frame1 = Frame(master, borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black",
               highlightcolor="black")
frame1.place(x=listbox.winfo_width() + 10, y=5, width=300, height=listbox.winfo_height())
canvas1 = Canvas(frame1)
frame2 = Frame(canvas1, height=500)
scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=canvas1.yview)
canvas1.configure(yscrollcomman=scrollbar1.set)
scrollbar1.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas1.pack(side="left")
canvas1.create_window((0, 0), window=frame2, anchor='nw')
frame2.bind("<Configure>", myfunction)

printbutton = Button(master, text="Print", command=printcommand)
printbutton.place(x=100, y=250)

checkbuttons = {}
for item in list_for_listbox:
    listbox.insert(END, item)
    checkbuttons[item] = (dict())
    for y in enable:
        temp_var = BooleanVar()
        checkbuttons[item][y] = [temp_var, Checkbutton(frame2, text=y, variable=temp_var)]

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

print(enable)

mainloop()

printcommand()
```

**[VERSION WITH DYNAMIC VARIABLES]**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def myfunction(event):
    canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))


def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
    w = evt.widget
    x = 0
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))

    for y in enable:
        for item in list_for_listbox:
            globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(item, y)].grid_forget()
        globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(value, y)].grid(row=x,column=0)  
        # here you can add Text
        x += 1


master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Checkboxes test")
master.geometry("750x500")

enable = ['button 1', 'button 2', 'button 3', 'button 4', 'button 5', 'button 6', 'button 7']
list_for_listbox = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.place(x=5, y=5, width=100, height=10 + 16*len(list_for_listbox))
listbox.update()

frame1 = Frame(master, borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
frame1.place(x=listbox.winfo_width() + 10, y=5, width=300, height=listbox.winfo_height())
canvas1 = Canvas(frame1)
frame2 = Frame(canvas1, height=500)
scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=canvas1.yview)
canvas1.configure(yscrollcomman=scrollbar1.set)
scrollbar1.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas1.pack(side="left")
canvas1.create_window((0, 0), window=frame2, anchor='nw')
frame2.bind("<Configure>", myfunction)

for item in list_for_listbox:
    listbox.insert(END, item)
    for y in enable:
        globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)] = BooleanVar()
        print("checkbox" + item + y)
        globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(item, y)] = Checkbutton(frame2, text=y,
                                                                variable=globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)])

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

print(enable)

mainloop()

for item in list_for_listbox:
    for y in enable:
        print(item + " [" + y + "] " + str(globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)].get()))
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: for adding text widgets you can add code in "onselect(evt)" like:
Label(frame2,text="some text").grid(row=x,column=1)

Comment: Sorry, i had a little bug in code, i fixed it, please copy code again or replace the "place_forget()" with "grid_forget()". Thanks.

Comment: Using `globals` in this way makes the code really hard to understand. You should consider storing the checkbuttons and variables in a dictionary or list.

Comment: I agree with you, but in his matter, if he wants to do anything with a poll, then maybe it's good idea that he just has to change the two lists and not the rest of the code. The infinite, automatic creation of the tkinter widgets is thought to be of use.

Comment: This [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52728070/8980073) of code needs an bigger modification if you want to edit lists, and the code is much longer. So my code is the ultimate code reduction...

Comment: Imagine, he makes thirty lists with 100 entries each ... then the dictionary will be very long and maybe hard to understand too.

Comment: The size of the dictionary is irrelevant. You either have 30*100 entries in a dictionary, or 30*100 variables. With the dictionary, at least they will be easier to manage.

Comment: I have revised the answer. Thanks for discussing with me; D That is not self-evident!